How to test for "No significant difference"?
my company is in game development. We are trying to test if adding some more ads in specific places will effect the players engagement badly (decrease playtime, retention,...).
Can you guys advise me on how to conduct and analyze the A/B test? Normally, we test and use t-test to analyze for significant difference, not the other way around, so I am a little confused here.

See our equivalence tag: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equivalence?tab=Votes

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
